# How did the GoFast 2014 Rocket de-spin?

Tags: amateur-rocketry

In [this awesome Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=001IXnp0ogc) of HD footage from the [GoFast 2014 Rocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civilian_Space_eXploration_Team#Space_Shot_2014_.22GoFast.22_Rocket), a de-spin maneuver is performed. Is this a [yo-yo de-spin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yo-yo_de-spin)?

You can see the de-spin at [0:57](https://youtu.be/001IXnp0ogc?t=56) and at [3:47](https://youtu.be/001IXnp0ogc?t=225), where it really looks like a bolo is flying away, but I can't be certain. It's only a few frames and it's not possible to slow-mo Youtube videos (or frame advance). YouTube frame advance. Pause video. Press period key to advance and comma key to back up one frame at a time.

[image]

The video is great - even though there is no sound in space, the vibrations of the craft are picked up by the cameras.

Comment: @zdcyclops Thank you very much for "YouTube frame advance. Pause video. Press period key to advance and comma key to back up one frame at a time." I never knew that and myself have spent hours double-tapping the space bar as a poor approximation for frame advance.

Comment: @uhoh I'm glad you learned something. From the stuff I see on space exploration, you're a bright person!

Comment: Oh absolutely not! I'm just an SE addict and spend an inordinate amount of time in this ASCII world; mostly learning from others. It's really the *asking of questions* that drives the site. Because you asked this question I found out what a yo-yo de-spin was in the first place!

Comment: Well, don't thank me, thank the editor of the question 

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't have any direct information but I can't think of anything else it could be.

If it were roll thrusters (cold gas or monoprop) you'd expect to see much slower response (because you'd want them to be no larger/heavier than necessary), they'd have continuous control, and there would be controller artifacts -- overshoot or undershoot.

I don't think a reaction wheel of any reasonable flywheel/battery mass could give that kind of performance.

The sound on the video seems consistent with an unwinding cable of some kind - rasp-and-clunk, with the deceleration on the clunk.

Answer (score 5):

I shortly after found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L4eY_N9IS3w), which confirms it's a yo-yo de-spin.

I wonder why this guy called his video "flat Earth dome". I didn't spend any time looking at his other videos, but it appears he's a flat Earth believer, and if so, can't be trusted...

I would like to have a more reputable source.

Comment: I watched a couple videos. Crazy dude.

Comment: Some people are limited to using common sense in what they see and calling them crazy is not fair. I have yet to see a believable answer to the original question. I do not, and have never believed in a flat earth or domed earth but cannot deny the video and answers leave unanswered questions. This is why people do not trust scientists (climate), government and govt. organizations (space). Just my humble opinion. Isn't asking questions and figuring out how things work what we all love to do?

Comment: @RichBianco When you say you have yet to see a believable answer to the original question, are you talking about the yo-yo despin, or flat Earth?

Comment: the way the rocket stopped spinning suddenly. It may be because this is not my area of knowledge, I'm a computer programmer. But even so I like to try and understand things. The video gives credence to a conspiracy I don't believe in and would like to inform people with good information, the reason I came here to ask experts. But I'm getting beat up with negative votes, not welcome here. thanks though. I tried deleting another conspiracy related question for which I've researched the best I can, but someone will close it soon before I hit negative rating

Comment: @RichBianco Did you read the article on yo-yo despin linked in the body of the question?

Answer (score 4):

Around `03:45` in the [linked video](https://youtu.be/001IXnp0ogc?t=223) you can see (both?) Yo-Yo(s) deployed and move away from the spacecraft. The frame with the red box shows a small object which may be some retainer, followed by the Yo-Yo masses themselves.

There is another object fixed near the horizons, which is likely to be the just-past-full Moon on July 14, 2014 at 07:32 local time in New Mexico as shown by a screen shot from [in-the-sky.org](https://in-the-sky.org/skymap.php).

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]